# Tail index using hill estimator in R

Tags: r, time-series

As part of my data analysis (of heavy-tailed data) I wish to calculate the tail (for both left and right) indices of around 100 time series of company returns. My data is stored in a large zoo object, with company names as the header.

Here is my current way of calculating the hill estimators:

```
returns <- read.zoo("returns.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", format="%d-%m-%y")
returns_hplots <- lapply(returns, hillPlot)
returns_hill <- sapply(returns_hplots, function(x) x$y)
returns_hill <- sapply(returns_hill, '[', seq(max(sapply(returns_hill,length)))
```

As a result, I have a data frame [1:204, 1:105] for my 105 companies filled with all the hill estimators and NA's (so that all columns have the same amount of rows).

However, I would like to calculate the hill estimators for both left tail and right tail, currently there is only one hill estimator for the whole distribution (per company).

Therefore I would need to split my data according to the distribution.
I have searched for data splits based on distribution but have not found a good answer.
My idea would be to calculate the 50% quantile and then seperate my data based on this quantile.

```
returns_quantile <- sapply(returns, quantile, .5)
```

Which results in a 1:105 vector which contains all the 50% quantile values. Now I would like to seperate my returns zoo object based on this quantile like the following:

```
returns_left <- ...
returns_right <- ...
```

Does anyone know how to split the zoo object based on the quantile?
Or is there any other way of directly calculating the hill estimator only for the left/right tail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found some example code from other researchers who calculated the hill estimators for both upper and lower tails.

Here is my code for calculating the hill estimators for both tails:

```
returns <- read.zoo("returns.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", format="%d-%m-%y")
returns_upper <- lapply(returns, hillPlot, doplot=FALSE) #set doplot to false to speed up calculation
returns_upper <- sapply(returns_upper, function(x) x$y) #extract the hill estimators
returns_upper <- sapply(returns_upper, '[', seq(max(sapply(returns_upper,length))) #create a data frame where each column has equal length (easier analysis)

returns_lower <- lapply(-returns, hillPlot, doplot=FALSE)
returns_lower <- sapply(returns_lower, function(x) x$y)
returns_lower <- sapply(returns_lower, '[', seq(max(sapply(returns_lower,length)))
```

So my previous method (in the question) was actually only calculating the hill estimators for the upper (right) tail.

Comment: I was trying your code. statement: returns_upper <- sapply(returns_upper, function(x) x$y) gives error : Error in x$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Can you suggest something